# Conan 'CMake' helper exception thrown when building on Mac/Windows

Tags: cmake, conan

I'm trying to bring an environment variable through conan into CMake without building the project so I'm using the CMakeToolchain offered by Conan inside the conanfile

```
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, CMakeToolchain
...
def generate(self):
    tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
    tc.variables["SAMPLE_VAR"] = "SAMPLE_VAR"
    tc.generate()
```

The problem is that on Jenkins pipeline I'm getting this error when building on the Mac/Windows node (Debian seems to be working fine). From my knowledge the conan version running on the node is 1.60.1

```
[2023-07-18T12:25:58.188Z]  ConanException: Using the wrong 'CMake' helper. To use CMakeDeps, CMakeToolchain you should use 'from conan.tools.cmake import CMake'. Set environment variable CONAN_DISABLE_STRICT_MODE=1 to override this check (should only be used to build old packages).
```

My question is how does Conan want me to use the CMakeToolchain? I've included the CMake module just because of the error but in reality it's not even used.

Looking at the conan documentation they use it the same way:

```
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain

class App(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "arch", "compiler", "build_type"
    requires = "hello/0.1"
    generators = "CMakeDeps"
    options = {"shared": [True, False], "fPIC": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False, "fPIC": True}

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.variables["MYVAR"] = "MYVAR_VALUE"
        tc.preprocessor_definitions["MYDEFINE"] = "MYDEF_VALUE"
        tc.generate()
```

https://docs.conan.io/en/1.60/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmaketoolchain.html

Comment: This looks like a bug. If you can submit a ``conanfile.py`` that reproduces it and the full output to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, it should be investigated. I suspect that you still are using the legacy ``from conans import CMake`` somewhere, so a full ``conanfile.py`` would really help.

Comment: @drodri  I think you are right, I'm reusing a conan recipe which does use `from conans import CMake` via python_requires
What it's strange though is that I can't reproduce the issue locally, even if I include `from conans import CMake` in the actual conanfile.py

Comment: @JDGross Please, consider using Conan 2.x, I see you pointed Conan 1.x docs. There is a better tutorial https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/creating_packages/create_your_first_package.html. Plus, `conans` is no longer used, only `conan` namespace for imports.